# Unable to adjust php.ini max upload size directive on Centos 6.3

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6, wordpress, php5, mysql5

Currently i'm setting up **Centos 6.3** (64 bit) on vm and installing Wordpress:
Already adjust /etc/php.ini but seems like overwritten by other settings.

Suspect this is due to selinux feature. My goal is setting up all Wordpress with all feature working like Media files folder creation (permission issue), appropriate max memory and max upload size.

Any suggestion welcome. Thanks.

**OS environment snapshot**:
Linux 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 22 12:19:21 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Jul 12 2013 20:35:47) 
Zend Engine v2.3.0
MySQL version: 5.1.61 Source distribution

Comment: Can you upload small files? If yes - It's not a selinux. This can be limited on the webserver or php. Please update question with output of following: `rpm -Va "httpd*" "mod_*" "php*"` (wait for it!), `ls -l /etc/php.d`

Answer (score 0):

Check which php.ini is being used. On Command prompt run this command

> php -i |grep php.ini

This command will list the currently used php.ini file for system. You can adjust the max_upload limit and other options in this file. After making changes in that file, Restart Apache and you ar done.

Comment: Centos is using  /etc/php.ini thats php -i |grep php.ini said. Thought its not on the php.ini itself. Thats why i ask this question. :-)